# java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db' in hive

Tags: hadoop

I am a starter to hive. When I try to execute any hive commands:

`hive>SHOW TABLES;`

it's showing the below error:

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Failed to start database '/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
NestedThrowables:
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Comment: I think this should be posted on [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: The question is answered by me [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761139/java-sql-sqlexception-failed-to-start-database-metastore-db-error-while-init/25587527#25587527

Answer (score 5):

It looks like derby locking issue. you can temporarily fix this issue by deleting the lock file inside the directory `/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db`. But this issue will also occur in future also

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db/*.lck`

With default hive metastore embedded derby, it is not possible to start multiple instance of hive at the same time. By changing hive metastore to mysql or postgres server this issue can be solved.

See the following cloudera documentation for changing hive metastore

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered similar error when I forgot about another instance of `spark-shell` running on same node.

Answer (score 1):

update `hive-site.xml` under `~/hive/conf` folder as below name/value and try this:

```
 <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
 <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/var/lib/hive/metastore/metastore_db;create=true</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to create a directory and grant proper permissions:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/hive/metastore/
$ sudo chown hdfs:hdfs /var/lib/hive/metastore/
```